# urlsafe_base64_decode возвращает None

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В своем проекте я реализовал **подтверждение адреса электронной почты.**

Пользователь вводит в форму все необходимые для регистрации данные, после чего мы берем из атрибута `cleaned_data` адрес электронки и отправляем сообщение.

Отправку я реализовал следующим способом(куски кода после пояснений приложу):

1. Есть mixin, который наследуется от FormView и который определяет метод FormValid таким образом, чтобы в метод save формы отправлялись необходимые для отправки сообщения данные.
2. Мы наследуем представление от вышеуказанного миксина и определяем поля, впоследствии используемые в отправке.

**Вот mixin:**

```
class SendsMessageMixin(FormView):
    """
    A mixin that provides all inherited
    classes with the functionality of sending an email.
    """

    email_subject = email_template_name = token_generator = None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        When this method is triggered, the data that will
        later be used to send the message is passed to the form save method.
        """

        form.save(
            **
            {
                'request': self.request,
                'use_https': self.request.is_secure(),
                'subject': self.email_subject,
                'template_name': self.email_template_name,
                'token_generator': self.token_generator
            }
        )

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Представление:**

```
class Registration(UnauthorizedRequiredMixin, SendsMessageMixin):
    form_class = ConsumerCreationForm
    template_name = 'consumers/registration.html'
    email_subject = 'Confirm your account.'
    email_template_name = 'mail/verification.html'
    token_generator = default_token_generator
    success_url = reverse_lazy('message_sent')
```

**Метод save формы:**

```
    def save(self, **sending_data):
        """
        Saves an inactive user to the database, after sending
        a message asking for confirmation of registration to the email address.
        """

        consumer = super().save(commit=False)
        consumer.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])

        prepare_data_and_send_message_with_uid_and_token(consumer=consumer, **sending_data)
        consumer.save()

        return consumer
```

**Генерация контента сообщения:**

```
def prepare_data_and_send_message_with_uid_and_token(request, consumer, use_https, subject,
                                                     template_name, token_generator):
    """
    Prepares data to be loaded into message content,
    the main purpose of which is to send a unique link to the user.
    """

    content = {
        'domain': get_current_site(request).domain,
        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(consumer.pk)),
        'token': token_generator.make_token(consumer),
        'protocol': 'https' if use_https else 'http'
    }

    send_message(subject, template_name, content, consumer.email)
```

**Отправка сообщения**

```
@task()
def send_message(subject, template_name, content, to_email):
    """
    Sends a message to the specified email address in the background.
    """

    body = render_to_string(template_name, content)
    message = EmailMessage(subject, body, to=[to_email])
    message.send()
```

Для фоновой отправки используется **huey**

**Само сообщение:**

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hello, your email address has been selected for registration!
To confirm, follow the link.
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
In case you didn't do it, just ignore this message.
{% endautoescape %}
```

При переходе на сгенерированную ссылку активации срабатывает метод dispatch, что в общем-то неважно по причине того, что метод здесь роли не играет.

В этом методе dispatch из словаря kwargs я достаю uidb64 и использую следующую конструкцию:

```
urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode().
```

Она возвращает None.

Самое главное, что None возвращается в любом случае. Хочу подчеркнуть, что uidb64 генерируется отлично и попадает в kwargs.

Добавлю еще одну особенность, что я пробовал переопределить форму восстановления пароля(с целью отправлять сообщение фоново) и при переходе на сгенерированную ссылку, то есть на вьюшку PasswordResetConfirmView, с уже готовой логикой, все сработало на ура и я смог восстановить пароль для учетной записи, а следовательно по uidb мой аккаунт был получен(decode сработал без возврата None).

Comment: а в метод `get_consumer` uidb64 вообще приходит то?

Comment: да, принтами проверял

Comment: а если убрать `.decode()` в `uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()` ?

Comment: None возвращает во всех вариантах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что в методе save формы регистрации, которая в том числе и вызывала метод подготовки данных и отправки сообщения, я вызвал его раньше сохранения самого инстанса модели в базе. Если проверить, то до отправки сообщения consumer.pk равен None, а уже после, когда сработал метод save у него появляется численное значение. Спасибо человеку под ником Мистер Фикс, что дал понять то, что никогда возвращаться None не будет, если ты сам None туда не отправил.

Подытоживая все сказанное: нужно было просто поменять местами две операции.

Answer (score 3):

Мой ответ: **Функция urlsafe_base64_decode не должна возвращать None, ни при каких обстоятельствах.**

Либо она где-то у вас в проекте перегружена, либо это ошибка самого питона(что вряд-ли), либо ошибка используемой версии джанги, либо вы сами пошли по неверному пути.

Где вы увидели None? И почему вы решили, что None вернула именно эта функция.
Предоставьте пример кода, который мы можем запустить, и который вернёт None. Тогда можно будет рассуждать.